# Accessing the trigger table inside the trigger's body

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, parameters, triggers

How can I access a table that has a trigger on inside the trigger's body?

```
create or replace trigger insert_try after insert on triggerTable for each row
begin
    insert into anotherTable (triggerFunction(:new.field1), 155,155); 
end;

create or replace function triggerFunction(param1 in number) return number as   
abc number;
begin
  select max(field1) into abc from triggerTable where field1!= param1;
  return abc ;
end triggerFunction;
```

This results in "SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04091". Is there any way to do the insert operation independent of the trigger and run the trigger afterwards?

Comment: The table `triggerTable` is mutating, because you are trying to select from the table which is currently being modified by the trigger.

Comment: So how can I select from this table? Is there a work around or another approach to achieve what I've described?

Comment: Why do you need that function at all? You could just use `:new.filed1`

Comment: I actually need to access the other rows in the table. It was just to illustrate the idea.

Comment: That's what I am saying, you could simply use `:new` to access the new value.

Comment: You can't access the other rows in "triggerTable". So you need to tell us what is you really requirements. Because the solution shouldn't access "triggerTable" but it can satisfy your requirements. Solution will depend on your requirements.

Comment: I need to calculate min and max values from the triggerTable again when there is a new row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to use the function which queries the same table on which the trigger is defined. It does nothing but sends the `:new.field1` as parameter and get's the same value back.

Since you already use **FOR EACH ROW**, you can access the old and new values as `:old` and `:new`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_try 
AFTER INSERT ON triggerTable 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO anotherTable
    (:new.field1, 155,155
    );
END;
/
```

It will simply insert the value from `field1` of `triggertable` into `anothertable`.

Comment: Please check my edited version. And the question is not "how can I insert a row into anotherTable."

Answer (score 0):

Make the function autonomous by using pragma autonomous_transaction

```
            create or replace function triggerFunction(param1 in number) return number as   
            abc NUMBER;
            pragma autonomous_transaction ;
            begin
              select max(field1) into abc from triggerTable where field1!= param1;
              return abc ;
            end triggerFunction;
```

Then try inserting , mutating table error will not come in this case .

Comment: Your where clause is "field1!= param1" that it mean you get max value without the newly inserted row. Why do you need to access the newly inserted row?